# Why background-image didn't work when print in css?

Tags: css, printing, sass

**This is my code in css**

```
background-image: url(${imgTitle});
background-size: 100% 30px;
padding-left: 10px;
margin: 10px;
```

**How to make it work?**

```
@media print{...}
```

or

```
Code.css
```

Comment: `@media print{...}`

Comment: I don't think your server-side code is processed on the print. Thoughts? Try hard-coding a URL -- does it work then?

Comment: It's a browser setting - most browsers default to not print backgrounds to save on ink.   The only way to be sure an image will print is to not have it in the background - you cannot force browsers to print the background using code (although you could try the non standard css in the duplicate answers - I wouldn't recommend putting that into production though)

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you very much